# How to get object property from each object in an array?

Tags: php

Assuming I have an array of objects in PHP, something like:

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Title One
        )    
    [1] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Title Two
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 7
            [name] => Title Seven
        )
)
```

What is the best way (i.e. fastest) to get an array of the IDs? i.e. `array(1,2,7)` I can loop manually but I feel there must be a better method.

Just saw [this in the similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118994/php-extracting-a-property-from-an-array-of-objects) but there's a little debate over whether the accepted answer is really the best way, plus it's from 2 years ago. I'm on PHP 5.3.

Comment: Depending on your scenario, you may want to consider using an [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) instead of an array of objects with an `id` member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest way is simply looping (`foreach`, `for`, `while`). Using callback functions will incur unnecessary overhead.

I would look to see if there's a way to create the list via the code that is building the initial array of objects.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) to get the IDs from each element.

```
function getID($a){
   return $a->id;
}
$IDs = array_map('getID', $array);
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/nf3ug

Answer (score 6):

Since PHP 7.0 you may use the builtin function `array_column` for that, which takes an input array and the name of the property you want to pluck:

```
$ids = array_column($input, 'id');
// array(0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 7)
```

As a third parameter, you may optionally supply an index-key as well:

```
$ids = array_column($input, 'name', 'id');
// array(1 => 'Title One', 2 => 'Title Two', 7 => 'Title Seven')
```

Please note that, although it's already available in PHP 5.5.0, support for an array of objects was first introduced in PHP 7.0.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using RedBean and for some reason passing in "getID" didn't work for me, so here is how I done it:

```
$ids = array_map(function($val){return $val->id;}, $objects);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily with [ouzo goodies](https://github.com/letsdrink/ouzo-goodies)

```
$result = array_map(Functions::extract()->id, $objects);
```

or with Arrays (from ouzo goodies)

```
$result = Arrays::map($objects, Functions::extract()->id);
```

Check out: http://ouzo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/utils/functions.html#extract

See also functional programming with ouzo (I cannot post a link).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the [array_keys](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) function?

**EDIT:**

```
<?php 
   $ids = array();
   for($c=0; $c<count($the_array); $c++) $ids[$c] = $the_array[$c]->id;
?>
```

Comment: In the example, `array_keys` would return `[0,1,2]` not `[1,2,7]`. But I guess I could store the IDs as array keys...

Comment: Yes, that's right. I think that the iteration is mandatory. If you wouldn't like to iterate, the use of functions like array_map will do it for you in any case and this will incur in unnecessary overhead caused by calling the callback function (as reported by @webbiedave). I'm editing my post by adding the "obvious solution".

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [extract_property()](https://github.com/dcelasun/extract_property) which is a well tested library designed specifically for this job (disclaimer: I am the author).