# output one property for all objects in array

Tags: php, arrays

what is a quick and clean way to output a property for each object in an array. for example:

```
$array=[object1,object2,object3];
```

now I only need to get the name for each object:

```
object->name;
```

and output as a string like

```
name1,name2,name3
```

I don't like using for loop, I guess there is a quick way in php, please advise. thanks.

Comment: "I don't like using for loop" => too localized

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting a property from an array of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118994/php-extracting-a-property-from-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get object property from each object in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462150/how-to-get-object-property-from-each-object-in-an-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `array_map` to project your array of objects into an array of property values; after that `implode` can make you a nice little string of values:

```
$array = [ /* ... */ ];
echo implode(',', array_map(function($el) { return $el->name; }, $array));
```

Comment: Nice alternative, but how is that going to be any faster than a loop?

Comment: @StevenDeGroote: First of all, being faster was not mentioned in the question. That said, although I certainly don't know if it's going to be faster or not, I can definitely see how it *could* be faster: `array_map` is directly implemented in C while `foreach` is implemented as part of the PHP VM which should (in general) be much slower. On the other hand I would expect `foreach` to be heavily optimized since it's so common, hence I couldn't say without measuring.

Comment: this is what i am looking for, just one line of code.thanks.

Comment: @bingjie2680 just because its one line of code doesnt make it better. you can write your foreach into one line of code, too. One-liners are **not** some sort of l33t $k1ll. You are supposed to write readable code. The above could easily be formatted to span three to five lines of code to improve readability.

Comment: @bingjie2680: As others have said; this is not "better" because it's one line, or one statement. It *could* be better because it's side-effect-free and chainable, but don't lose the forest for the trees.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, guys, I am using this in a view file, so one line of code is more readable in my case. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can with a foreach loop:

```
 foreach ($array as $value) {
      $value->name;
 }
```

If you don't know how many elements are in your array, I don't know how you could do this without any sort of loop.

Answer (score 1):

My goodness! What's wrong with a loop? It's one of the most basic programming constructs.

Sure, you could use a closure instead:

```
array_walk($array, function($item) {
   echo $item->name . ",";
});
```

or:

```
echo implode(",", array_map(function($item) {
   return $item->name;
}, $array));
```

But is that really easier to comprehend than:

```
foreach($array as $item) {
  echo $item->name . ",";
}
```

Now please get over the fact you will need loops in programming. Lots of them!

Answer (score 0):

You mean like

```
$str = $array[0]->name . ',' .
$array[1]->name . ',' .
$array[2]->name;
```

If you want it to be dnymic, well, you have to iterate:

```
$str = '';
foreach($array AS $object){
  $str .= ',' . $object->name;
}
```