# PHP. Is it possible to use array_column with an array of objects

Tags: php

Is it possible to pass in `array_column` an array of objects?
I have implemented ArrayAccess interface, but it has no effect.
Should I implement another one?

```
class Foo implements ArrayAccess {

    public $Id, $Title;

    public function offsetExists($offset)
    {
        return isset($this->{$offset});
    }    

    public function offsetGet($offset)
    {
        return $this->{$offset};
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value)
    {
        $this->{$offset} = $value;
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset)
    {
        unset($this->{$offset});
    }
}

$object = new \Foo();
$object->Id = 1;
$object->Title = 'Test';

$records = array(
    $object, 
    array(
        'Id' => 2,
        'Title' => 'John'
    )
);

var_dump(array_column($records, 'Title')); // array (size=1) 0 => string 'John' (length=4)
```

Comment: How about creating a custom function to do this for you? Array_column is targeted just for arrays and while ArrayAccess is implemented, array_column is a built in function of php so it is difficult to ascertain exactly how the function works.

Comment: What are you expecting to be returned?

Comment: @Anthony, I expect the same result as if it was simply an array instead of object. In other words, I want property "Title" to be returned.

Comment: can convert array of objects to array of column by `$array = json_decode(json_encode($array), TRUE);`

Answer (score 167, accepted):

PHP 5

`array_column` doesn't work with an array of objects. Use `array_map` instead:

```
$titles = array_map(function($e) {
    return is_object($e) ? $e->Title : $e['Title'];
}, $records);
```

PHP 7

`array_column()`

> The function now supports an array of objects as well as
>   two-dimensional   arrays. Only public properties are considered, and
>   objects that make use of   `__get()` for dynamic properties must also
>   implement `__isset()`.

See https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.0.0/UPGRADING#L629 -
Thanks to [Bell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2578286/bell) for the hint!

Comment: You won't gain any better performance if you need it to work with arrays **and** objects.

Comment: PHP 7.0 will support objects in array_column: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.0.0/UPGRADING#L629

Comment: For anyone interested in the actual code change, the original pull request can be found [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/1325); disclaimer, it's mine :D

Comment: @Ja͢ck OK, about an array of objects is clear. But what about the situation when we have an object that implements the array / iterable and other interfaces and returns objects in loop?

Comment: @StanislavBelichenko do you have an example of this, perhaps in a fiddle?

Comment: @Ja͢ck np and thx for the quick response!
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/13064739cbbdd17f76cea2eb93cfd9a45b42c44f

Comment: @StanislavBelichenko The type assertion is quite strict in this case, and only accepts true arrays. It would tell you this when your error reporting is configured properly :)

Comment: @Ja͢ck Very sorry. I hope this will be fixed in future versions of the language if this fix is correct from the point of view of its design.

Comment: @StanislavBelichenko i’ll see what i can do :)

Comment: Don't forget that as of PHP 7.4 you can use an arrow function. it's better because the code is more readable and is on the same line : `$titles = array_map(static fn($e) => is_object($e) ? $e->Title : $e['Title'], $records);`

Answer (score 17):

> Is it possible to pass in array_column an array of objects?

**PHP 7**

Yes, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

**PHP 5 >= 5.5.0**

In PHP 5 `array_column` does not work with an array of objects. You can try with:

```
// object 1
$a = new stdClass();
$a->my_string = 'ciao';
$a->my_number = 10;

// object 2
$b = new stdClass();
$b->my_string = 'ciao b';
$b->my_number = 100;

// array of objects
$arr_o = array($a,$b);

// using array_column with an array of objects
$result = array_column(array_map(function($o){return (array)$o;},$arr_o),'my_string');
```

PS: for clarity I prefer to not use `array_column` and use array_map with an anonymous function

```
$result = array_map(function($o){ return $o->my_string; }, $arr_o);
```

or a simple `foreach`

```
$result = array();
foreach($arr_o as $o) {
    $result[] = $o->my_string;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a function that will work on both php7 and php5

```
function array_column_portable($array, $key) {
    return array_map(function($e) use ($key) {
        return is_object($e) ? $e->$key : $e[$key];
    }, $array);
}
```

You can then use it as you use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) in php7

Answer (score 1):

While it's not possible to use `array_column` on child-objects, you can cast them to arrays. This is of course not the way to go, but it's a way.

**Using `array_map/get_object_vars`** (doesn't not work in your case, due the containing array)

```
array_column(array_map('get_object_vars', $thingy), 'property');
```

**Using `json_decode/json_encode`**

```
array_column(json_decode(json_encode($thingy), true), 'property');
```

https://eval.in/597950

*Note: Using json brings not the same result as using a true recursive function. You’ll lose protected and private properties of the object. But in some situations its fine.*

```html
function object_to_array($object) {
  if (is_object($object)) $object = get_object_vars($object);
  return is_array($object) ? array_map(__FUNCTION__, $object) : $object;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is prepare that array of objects:

```
$objectsList = [];

foreach ($objs as $obj) {        
    $objectsList[] = (array)$obj;
}

$propList = array_column($objectsList, 'prop');
```

Comment: Be aware of casting objects to arrays:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting

Comment: So, you are recommending that the entire array of objects structure be fully iterated to cast the objects to arrays, then iterate the entire data set again with `array_column()`? I wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Just so there's an explicit answer using `array_column()`: the code as given in the question will work with modern PHP versions since 7.0. `array_column()` will happily work with public object properties and/or array keys in the array elements:

```php
$object = new \stdClass();
$object->Id = 1;
$object->Title = 'Test';
$records = [$object, ['Id' => 2, 'Title' => 'John']];
print_r(array_column($records, 'Title'));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Test
    [1] => John
)
```