# Multidimensional Array Sum Column

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array with a **race type** column and a **boats** column (which has the total number of boats for each race type). This is how I am getting the array values:

```
$boats = $wpdb->get_results("
        select rt.race_type
              ,sum(tr.boat_count) boats
          from registrations tr
         group by rt.race_type;
");
```

The array works perfectly fine. But now I am trying to get the total number of boats for all race types (without using a loop). After some research, I have tried the code below, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
$totalboats = array_sum(array_column($boats,'boats'));
```

When I run the following command:

```
echo $totalboats;
```

The result of that is 0, which is clearly wrong.

Any ideas? I am running PHP 5.6.29.

***================== EDIT 01 ==================***

As requested, here is the **var_dump** of **$boats**:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#672 (2) {
            ["race_type"]=> string(12) "Elite 8-Hour"
            ["boats"]=> string(1) "2"
        }
    [1]=>
        object(stdClass)#673 (2) {
            ["race_type"]=> string(12) "Sport 4-Hour"
            ["boats"]=> string(1) "2"
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show the output of `var_dump($boats);` ?

Comment: It should be `sum(tr.boat_count) AS boats`, not `sum(tr.boat_count) boats`.

Comment: Per the documentation on `$wpdb->get_results` - it appears this method may actually hydrate into objects as opposed to a multidimensional array.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: @arkascha It works just as well without the `AS` keyword.

Comment: try this. first call array_column() funtion and store in to a variable and then call array_sum() function, without calling one function inside another function.

Comment: @roberto06 As request, I have added the var_dump on my original post.

Comment: @ashanrupasinghe Not sure why that would make a difference, but I tried it. Same results.

Comment: As @thinice suspected, `$wpdb->get_results` returns an array of objects. You need to convert these to arrays in order to use `array_column`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `$boats` sub-elements are objects and not arrays. `array_column` doesn't work with objects in PHP5 (it does in PHP7, though).

You could use a workaround using `array_map`, as shown in [this answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28883068) :

```
$totalboats = array_sum(
    array_column(
        array_map(
            function($o){
                return (array)$o;
            },
            $boats),
       'boats')
    );
echo $totalboats; // echoes "4"
```

Comment: At this level of complexity, you might as well use a `foreach()` and dispense with the type casting and `array_map()`

Comment: Agreed. Still, the original question stated *without using a loop*, so I took it as a challenge `;)`

Answer (score 0):

If your variable is  array and not object you can use this

```
$array = [
  0 => [
     'race_type' => 'Elite 8-Hour',
     'boats' => '2',
    ],
  1 => [
     'race_type' => 'Sport 4-Hour',
     'boats' => '2',
    ]
];



$toSum = array_sum(array_column($array, 'boats'));

echo "<pre>";print_r($toSum);die;
```

Comment: You mean he can use exactly what he's already using ? Shocking.