# Array Input saves as static Word 'Array' in SQL

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

Before, I managed to save an object inside the database. Now, I need to save each single data in an array in a row. I tried using array_column to save a specific set of data to a column but it saved as a word 'Array' instead. If I implode them, they will just go back to being saved as objects. I am using a  built in prepared statement called thingEngineer.

Frontend

```
<template>
<q-card
            class="exam-section"
            style="width:auto"
            v-for="(tdata, index) in testData"
            :key="index"
          >
            <h5>{{ index + 1}}. {{ tdata.question }}</h5>
            <q-input
              filled
              v-model="tdata.studentAnswer"
              label="Enter Your Answer Here"
              align="center"
            />
          </q-card>
</template>
<script>
export default {
 data() {
    return {
      option: [],
      testData: [],
      token: this.$store.state.token,
      subData: this.$store.state.subData,
      assignData: this.$store.state.assignData,
      testItems: this.$store.state.testItems,
      gotEm: false
    };
  },
methods: {
 submitMyAnswer() {
      console.log(this.testData);
      this.$store
        .dispatch("SAVE_STUDENT_ANSWER", {
          token1: this.assignData.teacher,
          token2: this.token,
          testData: this.testData
          // .testId,
          // studentAnswer: this.testData.studentAnswer
        })
        .then(response => {
          alert("Test Item Has Been Answered!");
          console.log(response.data);
        });
    }
}
}
```

Backend

```
  if (isset($_GET['submitId']) && $_GET['submitId'] == 2) {

            $testdata = file_get_contents('php://input');
            $testdecodedData = json_decode($testdata);
            $token1 = $testdecodedData->{'token1'};
            $token2 = $testdecodedData->{'token2'};
            $qna1 = $testdecodedData->{'testData'};
            // $qna2 = $testdecodedData->{'question'}; This was on the frontend 
            // $qna3 = $testdecodedData->{'studentAnswer'}; This was on the frontend 



            $qna2 = (array) $qna1;
            $qna3_val = array_column($qna2, 'question');
            $qna4_val = array_column($qna2, 'studentAnswer');


            $testAnswer = array(array(
                'AccessId' => $token1,
                // 'Question' => implode(", ", array_values($qna2)),
                'StudentAccessId' => $token2,
                // 'TestId' => implode(" || ", array_values($qna2_val)),
                'Question' => $qna3_val,
                'StudentAnswer' => $qna4_val
            ));

            $keys = array("AccessId", "StudentAccessId", "Question", "StudentAnswer");

            $insertTest = $db->insertMulti('answertable', $testAnswer, $keys);

            if ($insertTest) {
                echo json_encode($insertTest);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

array_column() returns an array of values based on column name.

Does $qna1 only have one question and answer attached to it and are the values strings?

If so, you should be able to just do this, unless I'm misunderstanding the question:

```
$qna3_val = $qna1->question;
$qna4_val = $qna1->studentAnswer;
```

Otherwise as an array:

```
$qna3_val = $qna2['question'];
$qna4_val = $qna2['studentAnswer'];
```

UPDATE: I don't remember one of your deleted comments about the details of the data structure, but for clarification this is the general idea of what I was thinking:

```
$testAnswers = array();
foreach ($qna1 as $questionData) {
    $testAnswers[] = array(
        'AccessId' => $token1,
        // 'Question' => implode(", ", array_values($qna2)),
        'StudentAccessId' => $token2,
        // 'TestId' => implode(" || ", array_values($qna2_val)),
        'Question' => $questionData->question,
        'StudentAnswer' => $questionData->studentAnswer
    );
}

$keys = array("AccessId", "StudentAccessId", "Question", "StudentAnswer");

$insertTest = $db->insertMulti('answertable', $testAnswers, $keys);
```

Comment: Use `print_r($qna1)` and `exit()` to see what values are set in PHP. It sounds like question and answer are not getting passed in right. Add those vars to the if statement or create an additional if statement to make sure PHP has those variables before moving further in the code.

Comment: If it's showing an error that those fields are not available, then I don't think you're getting to the insertMulti().

Comment: Cool, hopefully that helps. I'm not familiar with thingEngineer to know what structure it needs to do the insertMulti() call. Check their documentation to see what it needs to look like and use print_r() and exit() to create that structure. Once it looks right, then test the database call again.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23335938/3103434). The approach depends on the version of PHP you're using.

Comment: Nice! It changed the array of objects into a set of array which separated them based on their specific key columns. However, how many I suppose to save them for each row in my database? Is this where the insertMulti comes in?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not familiar with thingEngineer, so you'd need to check their documentation for how the data needs to be structured so you can insert multiple records at once. If you're inserting to 'answertable' and your `$qna4_val` contains multiple answers, I'm guessing you would need to loop over the answers to create an array containing multiple records so you can call `insertMulti()` successfully, but it depends on their docs. Just FYI, it's hard to follow the comments here if you delete yours. Please mark this answer as accepted if it has helped.

Comment: UPDATE: Yeah, sorry about deleting my comments, there's not enough space for me to add more comments of mine. Also, I managed to insert them using foreach loop, although the answers are not matching up. I think the insertMulti is not working well with for loop (unless my methods are wrong)

Comment: No worries. I just updated my answer with the general idea of what I was thinking. You should only need to call `insertMulti()` once if that query builder works this way. You may need to debug the actual data structure that it requires and fields if I made a mistake, but add back in the `print_r()` and `exit()` before to the query so you can debug it more easily.

Comment: When I tried to follow the logic of insertMulti, I think it's impossible to equally insert each data using nested foreach (This is currently my first way of inserting arrays but now it's not doable with 2D arrays for me). Is there any other way to add data row by row?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216398/discussion-between-codebuddy7-and-spudly).