# Get a list of siblings term ids from current product category in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, siblings, taxonomy-terms

I want to retrieve a list of term Ids based on the current category ID.

At the moment I'm using the following code:

```
$product_cat_items  = get_queried_object();
$product_cat_id     = $product_cat_items->term_id;
$product_cat_child  = get_term($product_cat_id, 'product_cat');
$product_cat_parent = $product_cat_child->parent;

$product_cat_related= get_terms('product_cat', array( 'parent' => $product_cat_parent, 'exclude' => $product_cat_id ));
```

It's working and I get an array of the terms.
But the probem is, that I only need the IDs from the term object to get a list like this:

123,345,678

Is there any way to extract such a list from the `$product_cat_related` array?

This is the current output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(WP_Term)#26238 (10) {
    ["term_id"]=>
    int(177)
    ["name"]=>
    string(27) "Name"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(21) "name"
    ["term_group"]=>
    int(0)
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
    int(177)
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(11) "product_cat"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["parent"]=>
    int(140)
    ["count"]=>
    int(8)
    ["filter"]=>
    string(3) "raw"
  }
  [1]=> ....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since WordPress version 4.5.0, taxonomies should be passed via the "taxonomy" argument in the `$args` array *([see `get_terms()` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/))*.
Also `get_queried_object()` already gives a `WP_Term` Object when the queried Object is a taxonomy term.
Also you can use `'fields' => 'ids'` as an argument in `get_terms()`, to get only an array of **term Ids** instead of an array of `WP_term` Objects *(see [`WP_Term_Query` available arguments](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/))*.
To finish, you will use PHP `implode()` to get a string of coma separated terms Ids.

So your code will be instead:

```
$current_term = get_queried_object(); // Already a WP_Term Object

if ( $current_term->parent > 0 ) {
    $siblings_ids = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
        'parent'    => $current_term->parent,
        'exclude'   => $current_term->term_id,
        'fields'    => 'ids',
    ) );

    // Get a string of coma separated terms Ids
    $siblings_list_ids = implode(',', $siblings_ids);

    // Testing output
    echo $siblings_list_ids;
}
```

Tested and works.

Comment: I'm using the IDs to show posts from that category list. If I use my way and `'terms' => $idCats` in the tax query, everything works fine. With your way and `'terms' => array($siblings_list_ids)` I only get 10 posts?! `'posts_per_page'` is set to 30.

Comment: Okay, I guess I have to use `'terms' => $siblings_ids` without separate the IDs with comma

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25286095/1788961

For me this code works:

```
$idCats = array_column($product_cat_related, 'term_id');
```