# Woocommerce: products from other categories on the product page (cross products)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

There is a hierarchy of categories, for example

```
cat_1
- cat_1_1
- cat_1_2

cat_2
- cat_2_1
- cat_2_2

etc...
```

I want to display on the product page products from other categories that do not include this product.

If, for example, the product belongs to the category `cat_1_1`, then it is necessary:

1. Get the current product category (`cat_1_1`);
2. Get the entire category tree by the parent, which includes the received category from paragraph 1 (`cat_1, cat_1_1, cat_1_2`);
3. Show 5 of any products from any categories, except those received in paragraph 2.

Something like category-based cross-selling.

I think I stumbled upon the right solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63755303/get-a-list-of-siblings-term-ids-from-current-product-category-in-woocommerce), but in my case, for some reason, it returns all categories without excluding the category tree of the current product.

```php
$current_term = get_queried_object(); // Already a WP_Term Object

if ( $current_term->parent > 0 ) {
    $siblings_ids = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
        'parent'    => $current_term->parent,
        'exclude'   => $current_term->term_id,
        'fields'    => 'ids',
    ) );

    // Get a string of coma separated terms Ids
    $siblings_list_ids = implode(',', $siblings_ids);

    // Testing output
    echo $siblings_list_ids;
}
```

I will be grateful for any help)

Answer (score 1):

You have to get current product terms for that you can use the `get_the_terms()` function. then you can use `tax_query` to exclude that category product. try below code.

```
global $post;

$ids = array();

// Get the product categories
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ){
    $ids[] = $term->term_id; // add term id to an array.
}

// The Query    
$category_based_cross_selling = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $ids,
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        ),
    ),
) );

$postIds = array();

if ( $category_based_cross_selling->have_posts() ): 
    while ( $category_based_cross_selling->have_posts() ) : $category_based_cross_selling->the_post();
       
    endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This returns the current item multiple times.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple items?